# Final Fantasy 12: Attack power and strength attributes

Tags: final-fantasy-12

I'm very confused about how the calculation of the target's lost hit points works when you attack.

Are both attributes combined to determine your final attack, or do the attack power only affects the damage done by the weapons you are using?

How does it work?

Comment: How is this related to ubuntu? :/

Comment: Sorry, you are right

Comment: And one more thing, "how the calculation of the target's hit points works when you attack", you mean the hit points lost after an attack? "both attributes", you mean Strength and attack power?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 8 categories of weapons, each with their own formula:

**For unarmed damage:**

> DMG = [11 x RANDOM(1~1.125) - DEF] x STR x (Lv+STR)/256.

*With Brawler License, it becomes:*

> DMG = [(Lv+STR)/2 x RANDOM(1~1.125) - DEF] x STR x (Lv+STR)/256

**For One-handed swords, Two handed swords, Spears, Crossbows and Rods:**

> DMG = [ATK x RANDOM(1~1.125) - DEF] x [1 + STR x (Lv+STR)/256]

**For Poles:**

> DMG = [ATK x RANDOM(1~1.125) - MDEF] x [1 + STR x (Lv+STR)/256]

**For Maces:**

> DMG = [ATK x RANDOM(1~1.125) - DEF] x [1 + MAG x (Lv+MAG)/256]

**For Katanas and Staves:**

> DMG = [ATK x RANDOM(1~1.125) - DEF] x [1 + STR x (Lv+MAG)/256]

**For Axes, Hammers and Handbombs:**

> DMG = [ATK x RANDOM(0~1.111) - DEF] x [1 + STR x (Lv+VIT)/128]

**For Daggers, Ninja Swords and Bows:**

> DMG = [ATK x RANDOM(1~1.125)]- DEF] x [1 + STR x (Lv+SPD)/218]

**For Guns and Measures:**

> DMG = [ATK x RANDOM(1~1.125)]^2

**And bonus, for Magic:**

> DMG = [POW x RANDOM(1~1.125) - MDEF] x [2 + MAG x (Lv+MAG)/256)]

---

This means several things:

- You should use different weapons depending on the character: Basch will be better with weapons focused on Strength, like swords, while Ashe and Penelo will be better with weapons focused on Magic (I think) like Maces
- The second stat (for example speed for daggers) becomes more and more important as level goes up
- You should use different weapons based on the enemies. Some have really high DEF, but low MDEF (use poles, guns, or magic), while others have low DEF, but high MDEF (avoid Magic and poles). I usually try to have my characters focus either on a physical weapon and magic, or a physical and a magical weapon (like 2H swords and Poles)

(This is based on [this guide](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/459841-final-fantasy-xii/faqs/45900))